# SQL IF NOT IN syntax

Tags: sql, if-statement, sql-server-2016, notin

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the below code please?

```
IF (SELECT T0.U_DestType FROM OCRD T0 INNER JOIN ODLN T1 ON T1.CardCode = T0.CardCode WHERE T1.DocEntry ='4') NOT IN ('1','2','6')

BEGIN
SELECT 'SHOW_ERROR' FOR BROWSE
END
```

It compiles without error but doesn't give the expected result (declare SHOW_ERROR when the U_DestType is anything other than 1,2 or 6)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use count function
Try this way

```
IF ((SELECT count(T0.U_DestType) FROM OCRD T0 INNER JOIN ODLN T1 ON T1.CardCode = T0.CardCode WHERE T1.DocEntry ='4') NOT IN ('1','2','6'))==0)

BEGIN
SELECT 'SHOW_ERROR' FOR BROWSE
END
```

Answer (score 4):

use `Exists`

```
IF Exists 
 (SELECT 1 FROM OCRD T0 INNER JOIN ODLN T1 ON T1.CardCode = T0.CardCode WHERE T1.DocEntry ='4' and T0.U_DestType NOT IN ('1','2','6'))
Begin
--some quwery
End
```

There is a Chance that your join might return more than one value and your query will fail.

Comment: I think you want `exists` for the OP's logic, but this is definitely a better solution than using `count()`.